# Why is this map an identification?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let us define $\Delta^n=\{(t_0,...,t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mbox{ such that } t_i \geq 0 \mbox{ and } \sum_i t_i=1\}$ for $n \geq 0$. If $q(\mu_0,...,\mu_{n-1},t)=(t,(1-t)\mu_0,...,(1-t)\mu_{n-1})$ is a map $\Delta^{n-1}\times [0,1] \to \Delta^n$, why is it an identification?

Id est, why $A \subset \Delta^n$ is open if and only if $q^{-1}(A)$ is open?

Comment: The only nontrivial part is the $t=1$ slice maps to a single point.  Any ball of radius $r$ about the point $(1,0,\dots,0)$ ($t=1$) is going to contain the image of the $t\geq 1-\epsilon/n$ slices, which is precisely what the identification of $t=1$ slice is doing topologically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a map between compact Hausdorff spaces, so it's a closed continuous map, and in particular a quotient map (aka an identification map).

Short proof: if $A \subseteq \Delta^n$ is open, so is $q^{-1}[A]$ as $q$ is continuous ( I think that's easy enough to see), and if $q^{-1}[A]$ is open, $(\Delta^{n-1}\times [0,1]) \setminus q^{-1}[A]$ is closed, hence compact and so $q[(\Delta^{n-1}\times [0,1]) \setminus q^{-1}[A]]$ is compact (by continuity of $q$), hence closed and the complement of that set is precisely $A$.

Comment: Just a nitpick: Quotient maps must be surjective. But that is trivially true here.

Comment: @PaulFrost The OP was only interested in the characterisation of open sets, not surjectivity, and moreover not all quotient maps are assumed to be onto. Texts differ there. I didn't want to presume.